# Kohana won't read session data in database

Tags: php, session, kohana

a few minutes ago i deployed a new version of my application to stage instances. After trying to login i have following error:

```
Session_Exception [ 1 ]: Error reading session data. [Details: Database_Exception [ ]: ~ MODPATH/database/classes/Kohana/Database/MySQL.php [ 108 ] ]
```

Stackoverflow is full of these errors, but no possible answer helped me.

My database config file:

```
 <?php defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No direct access allowed.');

return array
(
'default' => array
(
    'type'       => 'MySQL',
    'connection' => array(
        /**
         * The following options are available for MySQL:
         *
         * string   hostname     server hostname, or socket
         * string   database     database name
         * string   username     database username
         * string   password     database password
         * boolean  persistent   use persistent connections?
         * array    variables    system variables as "key => value" pairs
         *
         * Ports and sockets may be appended to the hostname.
         */
        'hostname'   => '127.0.0.1',
        'database'   => 'MY_DATABASE',
        'username'   => 'MY_USER',
        'password'   => 'MY_PASS',
        'persistent' => FALSE,
    ),
    'table_prefix' => '',
    'charset'      => 'utf8',
    'caching'      => FALSE,
),
'alternate' => array(
    'type'       => 'PDO',
    'connection' => array(
        /**
         * The following options are available for PDO:
         *
         * string   dsn         Data Source Name
         * string   username    database username
         * string   password    database password
         * boolean  persistent  use persistent connections?
         */
        'dsn'        => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=kohana',
        'username'   => 'root',
        'password'   => 'r00tdb',
        'persistent' => FALSE,
    ),
    /**
     * The following extra options are available for PDO:
     *
     * string   identifier  set the escaping identifier
     */
    'table_prefix' => '',
    'charset'      => 'utf8',
    'caching'      => FALSE,
),
);
```

Already tried to change hostname to `localhost` - no effect. Everything else looks fine.
The database connection must be correct, because i have a new entry in my session table (so the user is able to read & write new tuples into the session table).

The application use session setter / getter. When the application calls the session getter, the getter try to set a new instance:

```
/**
 * Session Getter
 * @return tye
 */
public static function getSession($key = null) {
    // Check, if session is given
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
        self::$_session = Session::instance();
    }

    if (!empty($key)) {
        return self::$_session->get($key);
    }
    return self::$_session;
}
```

`Session::instance()` execute the following code in `SYSPATH/classes/Kohana/Session.php [ 54 ] » Kohana_Session_Database->__construct(arguments)`

```
 //  Create a new session instance
 Session::$instances[$type] = $session = new $class($config, $id);
```

Argument Dump `$config`:

```
array(4) (
"group" => string(7) "default"
"table" => string(8) "sessions"
"gc" => integer 500
"columns" => array(3) (
    "session_id" => string(10) "session_id"
    "last_active" => string(11) "last_active"
    "contents" => string(8) "contents"
)
)
```

Argument Dump `$id`:

```
NULL
```

Following function produce the error (never modified!):

```
    /**
     * Select the database
     *
     * @param   string  $database Database
     * @return  void
     */
    protected function _select_db($database)
    {
            if ( ! mysql_select_db($database, $this->_connection))
            {
                    // Unable to select database
                    throw new Database_Exception(':error',
                            array(':error' => mysql_error($this->_connection)),
                            mysql_errno($this->_connection));
            }

            Database_MySQL::$_current_databases[$this->_connection_id] = $database;
    }
```

The application is working fine on my local system. So i think it's might be an error in php.ini. That's why i tried to set the following by `ini_set` in my index.php

```
    ini_set('session.auto_start', 0);
```

Without any success..

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the default session adapter in the `bootstrap` file.

```
Session::$default = 'database';
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be any number of reasons this happens. Kohana un-helpfully disguises the actual exception with it's own generic exception. I recommend temporarily throwing the original exception in the catch block to see what's really going on.

http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Session#read

In my case, it was from a deprecation warning about "mysql" and the need for "mysqli" or "pdo". Because, I had forgot to return my MAMP PHP mode back to individual PHP versions.